# PSPP can't access /home (or any other folder)

Tags: home, zorin

This is an issue I originally discovered on Zorin 16 but it also occurs on Ubuntu 20.04.
A freshly installed PSPP can't access /home folder or any other folder. Right now I can't think of any further info I could give to provide additional information: There are no error messages in the terminal or in GUI that I could provide. I thought of some missing permission to read directories and / or something I could do with groups attached to the user (but there is no pspp group). I am kinda clueless what I could do.
On Windows PSpp works fine but the PC's where it should be used run on Zorin right now.
Any ideas what I could check? Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: PSPP runs via flatpak. Flatpaks programs can be adjusted by using flatseal. Flatseal contains customization possibilities to customize rights to access folders. By default no (!) folders may be accessed by PSPP. So by installing flatseal and granting the rights to access fe home folder PSPP may open the files.